# Only keeping Then , can i have a separate scenario in gherkin

Tags: gherkin

Can i have separate scenario without Given and When steps, if you see last scenario, i have only then step as a separate scenario is it valid?
my feature file is about, i need to login to the application and i need to schedule a maintenance for 35 min, at 30th  minute i will get count down timer.
Respectively i will get countdown time at 5,4,3,2 and 1 minutes.
After verifying timer automatically application logs out and i need to verify whether i am in maintenance page

Scenario: Notification displayed 30 minutes before start of the maintenance
Given user is in "Home" page
Then system displays maintenance notification 30 minutes before logging out of the system

Scenario Outline: Notification displayed  minutes before start of the maintenance
When user closes the maintenance notification
Then system displays maintenance notification  minutes before logging out of the system

```
Examples:
  | time |
  | 5    |
  | 4    |
  | 3    |
  | 2    |
  | 1    |
```

Scenario: Maintenance page is displayed
Then system logs the user out of the system after maintenance starts
And system displays "Maintenance" page

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake while uploading the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no technical reasons to have the keywords `Given` `When` `Then` `And` or `But` in Gherkin. You can replace all of them with `*` and Cucumber will execute the steps in the order they are specified in the scenario.

So the answer to your question is, yes it is legal to only keep the `Then` step.

The follow up question is now, is it a good idea? The answer is probably, it depends. It depends on your audience that reads the scenario and expect to understand how the system is supposed to work. Will they be able to do so and have confidence that it is correct? Only your audience can answer that question so I would suggest that you ask them during a demo or similar session.